# Collapsing Toolbar not Collapse - On Scrolling, It remains same

Tags: android, android-coordinatorlayout, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I am using the following layout to implement coordinator layout with collapsing toolbar. But it didn't work. On scrolling, it remains the same. I am using listview in below fragment. Listview scrolling works but the collapsing toolbar not working. Please check the mistake in following code.

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/main_content"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent"
    app:layout_anchor="@+id/appbar"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom"
    app:tabGravity="fill"
    app:tabMode="scrollable" />

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/detail_backdrop_height"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
        app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

        <ImageView android:id="@+id/backdrop"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            android:background="@color/colorAccent"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
app:layout_anchor="@id/appbar"
app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"
android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
android:clickable="true" />
```

Comment: visit this : http://www.jayrambhia.com/blog/contacts-demo

Comment: Thanks for link ... But it didn't worked ... Same problem occurs